# Accessing NSString within NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Why can I not access the 4th element of an NSMutableArray when I initialise with a NSString object  rather than input the text manually?

For Example:

```
NSString * d = @"d";

self.arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
          [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",d,nil],
          [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"d",nil],
           nil];
```

This causes a beyond bounds error (NSString):

```
NSMutableArray *subArray  = [self.arr objectAtIndex:0];
question = [subArray objectAtIndex:3];
```

This doesn't (@"d"):

```
NSMutableArray *subArray  = [self.arr objectAtIndex:1];
question = [subArray objectAtIndex:3];
```

Why does this happen? Surely they are the same thing? I was hoping to reduce the amount of times I would have to write @"d".

Comment: have you try with     `NSLog(@"%@",[[self.arr firstObject ]objectAtIndex:3]);`

Comment: Is this for a quiz type of app? There are other ways you can store the answers.

Comment: This code worked perfect. There is no beyond bounds error.

Comment: This code looks good to me. One thing to try is to log the whole array and see if it's what you expect (`NSLog(@"%@", self.arr)`). It's possible that `d` isn't really set to what you think it is, and it's in fact nil at the time of array creation.

Comment: I agree with @Bhumeshwerkatre , there are no errors in this piece of code.

Comment: Clean your project, close and reopen Xcode. Run again.

Comment: @Mat Just curious, why do you think this helps?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper It's just a classic way to refresh Xcode's buggy brain ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be same... i tried following in my project. it works well.

```
NSString * d = @"d";

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",d,nil],
                [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"d",nil],
                nil];

NSLog(@"0 array 4th:%@",[[array objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:3]);
NSLog(@"1 array 4th:%@",[[array objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:3]);
```

output is as followings:

```
2013-12-16 17:05:30.092 Demo[1005:60b] 0 array 4th:d
2013-12-16 17:05:30.094 Demo[1005:60b] 1 array 4th:d
```